# Passing parameters to controller in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller

I am new to AngularJs. I have a details page where I display the link like below:

```
<a href='/device-summary/"+ full.link.href+"'>"+ data_to_be_displayed+"</a>
```

In the above link, the `full.link.href` points to another host url i.e, http://www.hostname.port/list/items/12. I want the `full.link.href` to be handled in my routed defined inside the controller. How can I get this. Please let me know how to define the config inside the controller?

Comment: I want to define a route for "/device-summary/hostname.port/list/items/12" and get the value of `full.link.href` in the controller

Answer (score 0):

The angular router won't know "full.link.href" as a variable since all it receives is a string, what it can know is to expect its value and treat it as a route parameter.

See the example in angular docs which uses $routeParams:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route